# How to read a SPIR-V file?

Tags: spir-v

I am experiencing issues with compilation of some GLSL code to SPIR-V as such I want to check through the SPIR-V code.

I want to be able to read through the assembly.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The [SPIRV-Tools](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Tools) project has a disassember which you can use got get a textual form  of the SPIR-V.  The Tools are also provided in the Vulkan SDK, the `spirv-dis` executable is the one you want.